# Error:(7, 36) error: package example.com.test.databinding does not exist

Tags: android, data-binding

This is the First time i am using Data Binding ,and from Couple of Hours i am having above error. There is Sufficient question related to same Question but Not able to Solve this issue.

**Gradle Module APP**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "example.com.test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

**Main_xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="user"
            type="example.com.test.MainActivity" />

        <import type="android.view.View" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.firstName}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{user.lastName}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Modal Class**

```
public class User {

    public final String firstName;
    public final String lastName;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }


}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String sMan = "Test";


        ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        User mainActivityPresenter = new User(sMan,sMan);
         activityMainBinding.setUser(mainActivityPresenter);



    }
}
```

**Image is added of log**

[image]

I am not able to solve this issue.How can this issue be solved??

Comment: Have you tried File->Invalidate cashes/ restart... ?

Comment: sure.many time,but error is not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the Simple and Silly Error i have Done this Time.
Solved with Changing the MainActivity to User

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="user"
        type="example.com.test.User" />

    <import type="android.view.View" />

</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.firstName}" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{user.lastName}" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of things incorrect in your implementation.

1. Your model class should extend `BaseObservable`.
2. Your getters should be `@Bindable`
3. Your setters should call `notifyPropertyChanged(..)`
4. In your xml, you are saying that "user" is a `example.com.test.MainActivity`, while I think it is a `User`?
5. `User mainActivityPresenter = new User(sMan,sMan);` is also very weird. Call a `User` "user" and a `Presenter` "xxxPresenter". Don't call a User "presenter" if you want to write clear code.

... these are some things I see at a glance, there's probably more. Please read the documentation completely first, it will make your implementation a lot easier:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html